# how do i restart a svnadmin load from a revision

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

I have a dump file that I was loading when my connection to the server was terminated and the load stopped.  I was able to go into the new repository and see what the last revision was.  From what I have read, which is very little, it appears that I have to rebuild the dump file using the top of my existing dump file and then removing the sections corresponding to the revision numbers that have already been loaded.

Is it possible to begin the load without having to edit the initial dump file?

Comment: Why don't you just edit the dump file as described in [How to continue a load that has failed in Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780864/176646)?

Comment: I could edit the file, but it is a large file and it seemed like a "hack".  I would have assumed that there was a better way to restart a load and be able to pick it up at a revision.  It just seemed that editing such a large file, which takes a long time to even load in VI, and then hoping that I got the format correct was not the desired path.  If this is the only option, then so be it. I had read that link, which is what I refer to in the original message. In my case I was able to blow away the repository and rerun from the beginning without issue.

Comment: Considering that editing dump files is described in the official SVN documentation in the section about [filtering repository history](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering), I wouldn't consider it a hack. Just be aware of the following caveat: "If you do plan on manually editing the dump file...make sure your editor is not set to automatically convert end-of-line characters to the native format (e.g., `\r\n` to `\n`), as the content will then not agree with the metadata. This will render the dump file useless."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the second comment that ThisSuitIsBlackNot made is the correct answer.  Also, you can refer to the link in the first comment for additional details.
Thank you.